# How to get rid of this - message:{'You are not subscribed to this API.'}.?

Tags: reactjs, api

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    fetch("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/quickAnswer?q=How%20much%20vitamin%20c%20is%20in%202%20apples%253F", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "[host]",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "[key]"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        form className = 'searchform' >
        <
        input className = 'search-bar'
        type = "text" / >
        <
        button className = 'search-bar'
        type = 'text' > Submit < /button> < /
        form > <
        /div >
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Subscribe to that API? Also you now need to rotate the credentials you just publicly shared.

Comment: What @jonrsharpe said. https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys#api-key-rotation-or-resetting-a-compromised-api-key might help with this bt I'm not certain, I've not used the api before.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Did you manage to find any solutions?

Comment: Happened to me as well when I was using this API. I subscribed to the free tier and then the data started to flow. So please make sure that you're subscribed to the API which is different than singing up.

Answer (score 8):

> You have to select a pricing plan, even if it's the free plan. Go to "Pricing" on the page for the API, and select a plan. This fixed the issue for me.

https://api.rakuten.net/Top-Rated/api/e-mail-check-invalid-or-disposable-domain/discussions/9487/keep-getting-this-response-%22You-are-not-subscribed-to-this-API.%22

Answer (score 6):

if you have everything set up correct on RapidAPI I would suggest passing the key without using variables because maybe you are passing undefined. For undefined we get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you actually subscribe tothe api on rapid api hub if you aren't  subscribed to the api
you're going to get an error message that notifies you don't have an active subscription and your call will not
be successfulbe sure that you actually subscribe tothe api on rapid api hub if you aren't  subscribed to the api
you're going to get an error message that notifies you don't have an active subscription and your call will not
be successful

message: you are not subscribed to this api rapidapi

[video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1lbJvoPxwM)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select a plan whether it's a free plan or a premium plan.

https://rapidapi.com/tipsters/api/hotels-com-provider/pricing

Answer (score 1):

If you are subscribed to the free plan and still getting this error "message:{'You are not subscribed to this API.'}"

The problem might be related to the .env location. Try placing it inside root of your folder, rather than src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with GET, try this. And let me know, if it works or not.

```
state = {
    url:
      "<url>",
    header: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "<host>",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "<key>"
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .post(this.state.url, this.state.header)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("err" + err));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering this issue: the oversight I made was adding 'Bearer ' in from of the RapidAPI key. It should just be the key, without anything in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be stale, but helpful to someone else:

The first thing you want to do is to avoid placing it within `.env`.
Ensure it works properly within the code snippet (unsafe method) before placing it within `.env` (current best practice).

For instance, you should first do this:

```
const options = {
     'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'theVeryLenthyKey',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'theAPI.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};
```

Instead of this:

```
const options = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.THE_VARIABLE_NAME_YOU_USED,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'theAPI.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by simple directly passing key, like this

```
export const exerciseOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  },
};
```

don't pass the key through the `.env` file

Comment: You dont want to paste your api key in a public site like SO...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same response saying {message: you are not subscribed ... but I was, I made sure. So the problem was that it couldn't read from the .env file.
So I used the manual method of directly putting the key in the code while in the development phase, but when I deployed the project I added it in the environment variables of the hosting service and it was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing your key as variables, make sure you place your .env file in root folder (environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the process.env.REACT etc I had there and instead used the original key from rapidapi. And that worked.